Difference between sentence structures and syntactic patterns?
I was reading a website that

Sentence structure is the order of all the parts in a sentence: subject, predicate, objects, phrases, punctuation, etc.

And on the next page was

syntactic patterns are the acceptable word orders within sentences and clauses.

I am struggling to see the difference and English was never a strong subject of mine.
Can anyone please explain the two?

Bin the book! Punctuation isn't part of sentence structure any more than hats are part of your anatomy! That whole sentence about sentence structure is a car crash.

The second definition includes structure within clauses, among a number of other differences. The second also has the word acceptable so it's possible the first uses a different standard. And the second refers purely to syntax while sentences are things with both syntax and meaning. (Making no comment on the accuracy of either definition, they're clearly different.)

Oh dear. I've just looked up the source: Grammarly. Don't trust a single word written on that website. I's all complete total and utter junk. Take the sentence: "a verb is an action". Completely untrue. In "Bob survived the hurricane", Bob didn't perform any action. "The subject is the noun that does the action" <--Enough to make you want to weep. Not all subjects are nouns, and when subjects do contain nouns, the subjects are normally noun phrases consisting of more than one word. And the subject doesn't "do the action"! Consider "Bob received a blow to the chin" <--Bob did not do the action!

Like atomic structure when we were, at school, given a simplistic model that we could understand, but afterwards discovered the reality was both more subtle and more complex, so is language. 'Subject, verb and object' are fine for primary school. But language is far more sophisticated. Up-voted +1. I have the same confusion and am longing for a clear answer.

@Araucaria-Him "All complete total and utter junk." We'll hold you to that fully.

@YosefBaskin Please do, but I should have said "web page", not "website". I haven't read the other pages yet.

Isn’t it just trying to say that a given sentence has a structure, and that structure may (or may not) follow a syntactic pattern that is considered acceptable?

So let's look at the context in which those claims were made. Both are articles on Grammarly (1, 2) by Matt Ellis, someone with no particular expertise in English syntax whose advertised skills include search engine optimization and the use of "content marketing" to improve a site's "traffic and engagement." Both of those Grammarly articles, you'll note, end in the same two exactly identical paragraphs constituting an advertisement for Grammarly itself, not to mention the modal dialog that covers your screen before you can even read it.
The purpose of these articles is, one assumes, to ensure that anyone searching Google for (say) "english sentence structure" will land on (say) the first of these articles, which repeats the relevant keywords as many times as possible for search-engine optimization purposes. They will then, quite conveniently, also be given plenty of ads for Grammarly's services--the sort of services that are labeled "It's Free" when the website has a "Pricing" link at the top of the screen.
Presumably, the reason why one article repeats the keyword "sentence structures" so often, whereas the other repeats the keywords "syntax" and "syntactic patterns," is to ensure that search results for both sets of keywords are likely to produce results that are ads for Grammarly.
That is, to my knowledge, the only reason why the same person would write two largely overlapping posts differing mainly in terminology, without any attempt at consistent or coherent presentation. The plan has worked out just great: if you search Google for "english sentence structures," the relevant Grammarly page is the second result; if you search Google for "english syntactic patterns," the other Grammarly page is the first result. "Traffic and engagement" achieved!
Of course, I could spend time going over the numerous factual inaccuracies in those two articles, but frankly content of that sort isn't even intended to be an authoritative source of reliable information.

"Sentence structure" refers to the analysis of a particular sentence. E.g. you might say that the structure of the sentence

The boy hits the ball.

is

subject (the boy) -> verb (hits) -> direct object (the ball)

or

noun phrase (the boy) -> verb (hits) -> noun phrase (the ball)

"Syntactic patterns" refers to the general rules of proper grammar. E.g. the rule that articles go before nouns -- you can say "The boy" but not "Boy the". Or that active sentences typically have the form "subject -> verb phrase -> direct object", while passive sentences are "direct object -> verb phrase -> preposition -> subject".

There looks like a considerable overlap. << noun phrase (the boy) -> verb (hits) -> direct object >> VS << subject -> verb phrase -> direct object >>.

Yeah, I mixed up abstraction levels there

The verb phrase normally includes both the verb and its objects or other complements, though.

Thanks, corrected. The right way to display sentence structure and syntactic patterns is with a hierarchical format, like a sentence diagram.

@user553453 In other words, you found these two phrases side by side, but they're not categories, as if something goes into one or the other. Instead, they're phrases we might use when talking about language, but we might pick one when talking about sentences and another when talking about bigger or smaller chunks of language.

@AndyBonner I think that comment belongs to the question, not my answer.

Oh, it was more that my two cents don't amount to an answer of my own; they're just in support of your answer.
